# Does anyone know a program that does this?

Tags: settings

I come from Windows and it is the first time that I will be in Linux. It turns out that in windows there is an Intel application that allows me to modify the brightness, the saturation, the gamma.

The native color of the laptop is quite dull, and I would like to saturate it a bit. But I can not find anything to do it, search a thousand times in google and nothing, the section "color" in elementary settings is useless.

I do not know what else to do.

I put images of the windows application, although they are in Spanish.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xrandr is what you're looking for. I use it to tweak the gamma of my screen, but you can use it for all sorts of useful things.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr

Comment: The truth is that I am new, and the commands do not know how they work well.

when I put in the console "xrandr", I get resolutions, but no saturation or gamma.

Could you tell me how to modify gamma and saturation?

Comment: I found a guide and I can modify the brightness and gamma with these commands :)
$ xrandr --output **** --brightness 1

$ xrandr --output **** --gamma 0.7: 0.7: 0.7


I lack the saturation, if you could tell me how.

Comment: Are the changes permanent or do I have to do something to make them happen?

Comment: in the terminal enter: get-edid this till give you the name of your display. On mine is eDP-1. So an example command to set gamma would be: xrandr --output eDP-1--gamma 0.87:0.87:0.87 keep in mind that eDP-1 is my monitor name. Replace that with whatever is yours. Play with the levels to change the gamma to your liking.

Comment: The problem is that it does not stay saved, it restarts when I turn off the PC.

Is there any way to save it?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple ways. You could install Redshift and edit the redshift.conf which is located in the folder /home/username/.config/ (username being your username). There is a gamma line in the config file in which you can edit to whatever you want. The thing with Redshift is it will adjust the color of your screen at night, removing the blue tint and making the screen appear more redish. Though this setting can be changed within the redshift.conf as well.

Comment: The more complicated was is to create an executable script file, create a desktop file for it and add it to your start up.

Comment: Or you can execute the script each time you login. You can enter the xranr command string every time you login or you could set an alias in your .bashrc file for the xranr command and just type the alias in your terminal